# postgresql has different version in ubuntu minimal (server)

Tags: postgresql

I bought an vps (virtual private server) and have installed ubuntu minimal (server) 12.04 32 bit on it for openerp use, and one of the openerp requirement is installing the postgresql

I installed just simply like the usually

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

but went I execute this command

```
 createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser --pwprompt openerp
```

in postgres user it said:

```
postgres@furnia:~$ createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser --pwprompt openerp
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

and when I restart the postgresql with

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

it just skipped to next line and do nothing

I start to check the whole postgresql in my server, and I discover that it's different with the desktop version

thanks for helping

Comment: Which version do you have on each machine?

Comment: "*I start to check the whole postgresql in my server, and I discover that it's different with the desktop version*". Details? Different how?  What's the output of `apt-cache policy postgresql` and `lsb_release -a` on both machines? (Edit the question to add the info, comment here when done).

Comment: @Craig Ringer, sorry for late response, I heard from my friend that the 64 bit of ubuntu server is better than 32, and after its installed 64 bit postgresql runs normally. The difference is like the folder postgresql in /etc doesn't exist, and other missing files.

Comment: @ Jon Hanna, 9.1

Comment: If that's what fixed your problem, you could give it as an answer yourself, as it might help someone else in the future.

Comment: @everyone i found another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discover that the problem is at the locale settings, and simply fixed by command

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

export LC_CALL=en_US.UTF-8

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```